# PHP - Unexpected Global, expecting String in class

Tags: php, cakephp

In my class (Which is actually a CakePHP model) I'm trying to simply set a variable and then access it from inside a function but I'm getting the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GLOBAL, expecting T_FUNCTION in /path/to/file/file.php on line 120**

Line 120 onwards of my file is as follows:

```
global $accessid = 'accessid';
global $secret = "secret";
global $b = 0;
global $m = 0;

function generateCredentials() {    
    global $accessid;

    return $accessid;
}
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this inside a `class { }` definition?

Comment: It is indeed in a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll guess that this is within a class definition like:

```
class Foo {
    global $var;
}
```

You can't use this keyword there. The only keywords you can precede class properties with are the visibility declarations `var`, `public`, `protected` and `private`. Class properties are always properties of the class they're defined in, they cannot be global variables.

If you insist, you could get them from `global` within a function and set them to the properties:

```
class Foo {
    public $var;

    public function foo() {
        global $var;
        $this->var = $var;
    }
}
```

This is all extremely ugly though, especially since Cake gives you better tools to deal with these things, like the [`Configure` class](http://book.cakephp.org/view/924/The-Configuration-Class) to register values globally.

Or you probably just want to create simple class properties:

```
class Foo {

    public $accessid = 'accessid';
    public $secret = "secret";
    public $b = 0;
    public $m = 0;

    function generateCredentials() {    
        $this->accessid;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, your last example worked good for me. I didn't use the Configure class as these are variables just needed within this particular model.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear from your question what the context is.

**Free code** *(If this code is free-standing)*

You don't use [the `global` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) to define globals. Just declare them in [the global scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

```
$accessid = 'accessid';
$secret = "secret";
$b = 0;
$m = 0;

function generateCredentials() {    
    global $accessid;

    return $accessid;
}
```

**Class members** *(If your code is found inside a class definition)*

If you want to be able to access global variables from inside a class:

```
$accessid = 'accessid';
$secret = "secret";
$b = 0;
$m = 0;

class X {
   function generateCredentials() {    
       global $accessid;

       return $accessid;
   }
}
```

Or if you want class members, not globals:

```
class X {
   public $accessid = 'accessid';
   public $secret = "secret";
   public $b = 0;
   public $m = 0;

   function generateCredentials() {
       return $accessid;
   }
}
```

Notice that you need to specify *member visibility* in the latter example. Take a look at [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I make that change I then get the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /var/www/html/bookmarklet/app/models/bookmarker.php on line 120

Comment: @Probocop: We have no context for your code. We can't help you without knowing what's before and after it. Can you provide a _complete, minimal_ testcase that reproduces the error? Most notably, if this is inside a class definition (please provide full context next time!), you need to specify an access level for your variables. For example, `public $accessid = 'accessid';`. Please read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). I have added this information to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `global` only inside of classes/functions.

In PHP constants are global, example:

```
define('ACCESSID', '123456');

// inside the function ACCESSID is now available
function generateCredentials() {    
    echo ACCESSID;
}
```

Comment: Nonsense. It's a keyword you can use in functions to bring a global into scope. Constants are constants, not global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this

```
private $accessid;
private $secret;
private $b;
private $m;

function generateCredentials() {    
    global $accessid;
    global $secret;
    global $b;
    global $m;

    $this->accessid = $accessid;
    $this->secret = $secret;
    $this->b = $b;
    $this->m = $m;

    return $accessid;
}
```